# Deserialize Json into member class of a class

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have the following Json snippet:

```
{
  "lastUpdated": "2020-08-10T02:59:18+00:00",
  "providerName": "Some Provider",
  "language": "en-US",
  "movies": [
    {
    }
   ]
}
```

And these proposed class definitions:

```
[Serializable]

    public class JfoRoot
    {
        public JfoRoot()
        {
        }
    
        public string lastUpdated { get; set; }

        public string providerName { get; set; }

        public string language { get; set; }

    }

[Serializable]
    public class JsonFeedObject
    {        
        public JsonFeedObject()
        {
        }
        
        public JfoRoot jforoot { get; set; }
        
        public MovieObject[] movies { get; set; }
    }
```

I'd like to deserialize the Json using:

```
jfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonFeedObject>(File.ReadAllText(path), jsonSerializerSettings);
```

Using the above, I'd like to deserialize the first three Json fields into the JfoRoot class.  I tried using several approaches that included using `[JsonConstructor]` and providing a JsonConverter after reading the post [Using Newtonsoft.Json with nested custom classes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551530/using-newtonsoft-json-with-nested-custom-classes)

Nothing worked.  The JfoRoot class was 'null' after every attempt I made.  I feel I'm missing something obvious.  Or, maybe this can't be done.  Can someone shed some light if this is at all possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing worked"? How didn't it work? If you create a `JsonConverter` and apply it to your `jforoot` property within the `JsonFeedObject` class, you can instantiate the object within the `JsonConverter` and set the properties you need.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with a redesign of the classes I use.  Rather than using:

```
[Serializable]
    public class JsonFeedObject
    {        
        public JsonFeedObject()
        {
        }
        
        public JfoRoot jforoot { get; set; }
        
        public MovieObject[] movies { get; set; }
    }
```

I switched to:

```
public class JsonFeedObject : JfoRoot
```

It's such a simple change and it works to provide all deserialized fields.

Answer (score 0):

The object you are trying to materialize from the JSON, doesn't match the JSON object. If you  moved all of the properties from `JfoRoot` to the `JsonFeedObject`, then this would deserialize correctly

```cs
public class JsonFeedObject
{
    public JsonFeedObject()
    {
    }

    public string lastUpdated { get; set; } = default!;

    public string providerName { get; set; } = default!;

    public string language { get; set; } = default!;

    public MovieObject[] movies { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Then calling

```cs
var json = File.ReadAllText(path);
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonFeedObject>(json);
```

results in

```
[14:52:39 INF] {"lastUpdated": "2020-08-10T02:59:18+00:00", "providerName": "Some Provider", "language": "en-US", "movies": [{"$type": "MovieObject"}], "$type": "JsonFeedObject"}
```

To deserialize them to a sub object I had to add a constructor with the specific properties

```cs
public class JfoRoot
{
    public JfoRoot()
    {
    }

    public string lastUpdated { get; set; } = default!;

    public string providerName { get; set; } = default!;

    public string language { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class JsonFeedObject
{
    public JsonFeedObject(string lastUpdated, string providerName, string language, MovieObject[] movies)
    {
        this.jfoRoot = new JfoRoot
        {
            lastUpdated = lastUpdated, 
            providerName = providerName, 
            language = language
        };

        this.movies = movies;
    }

    public JfoRoot jfoRoot { get; set; } = default!;

    public MovieObject[] movies { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

```cs
var json = File.ReadAllText(path);
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonFeedObject>(json);
```

resulting in

```
[15:21:15 INF] {"jfoRoot": {"lastUpdated": "2020-08-10T02:59:18+00:00", "providerName": "Some Provider", "language": "en-US", "$type": "JfoRoot"}, "movies": [{"$type": "MovieObject"}], "$type": "JsonFeedObject"}
```

Comment: Moving these properties  to the base class does not fit the OP's only mentioned requirement which was: *"Using the above, I'd like to deserialize the first three Json fields into the JfoRoot class."*.

Comment: @wwd I'm aware that moving those fields into the base class works.  In fact, that's how I had coded it originally.  But, I now have a new requirement to separate it out into an additional class.

Comment: Give me just a minute.